# SWT Item color after selection in the list

Tags: java, list, colors, swt

I want to change the color of the items after i select them on my `List`.
The default color is blue, and this is my syntax:

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List list = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);

list.setBounds(1250, 160, 200, 300);
for(int i=0;i<40;i++) {
    list.add("asasd");
}
```

Comment: Does it need to be a list? With a header-less, single-column table it would be easy.

Comment: @ThomasS. Yes it need to be a list

Comment: @Alex Why? Can you elaborate? Because otherwise the answer will be "no" (or rather "not without a considerable amount of work").

Comment: @Baz
Ok give me a solution with a table and i will change the logic.
I want to select and get green item selection and use shift to select multiple items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, a solution with a `Table`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    // If you choose to create a Color instance yourself, remember to dispose() it!
    final Color highlight = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW);

    final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);

    table.addListener(SWT.EraseItem, new Listener()
    {
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            event.detail &= ~SWT.HOT;
            if ((event.detail & SWT.SELECTED) == 0)
                return; // / item not selected

            Table table = (Table) event.widget;
            int clientWidth = table.getClientArea().width;

            GC gc = event.gc;
            Color oldForeground = gc.getForeground();
            Color oldBackground = gc.getBackground();

            gc.setBackground(highlight);
            gc.fillRectangle(0, event.y, clientWidth, event.height);

            gc.setForeground(oldForeground);
            gc.setBackground(oldBackground);
            event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
        }
    });

    final TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);

    table.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            column.setWidth(table.getClientArea().width);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE).setText(Integer.toString(i));

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]